# можно ли переписать метод в методе при объявлении объекта

Tags: java

```
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();//рабочий метод который не совсем подходит
```

код из используемых библиотек

```
    public class XSSFSheet extends POIXMLDocumentPart implements Sheet {
      ...
      public Iterator<Row> rowIterator() {
          return this._rows.values().iterator();
      }
      ...
    }

    public class TreeMap<K,V>
       extends AbstractMap<K,V>
       implements NavigableMap<K,V>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
    { 
      ...
      public Collection<V> values() {
          Collection<V> vs = values;
          return (vs != null) ? vs : (values = new Values());//нужно переписать эту часть

      ...
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете создать анонимный класс, расширяющий испозуемый вами нефинальный класс и переопределить в нём к-л нефинальный метод

```
XSSFSheet sheet = new XSSFSheet(){
    //Переопределяйте тут
}
```

Comment: а если объект sheet передается в методе?     private void fromExcelToData(XSSFSheet sheet, String p, String f)'

Comment: @Ildar, переопределить уже созданный объект невозможно. Вам надо либо найти месо где он создаётся и переопределить его там или не использовать его, а написать свой собственный класс с нужными методами и использовать его.